# How to combine multiple tables together in postgresql that have the same columns but in different order?

Tags: postgresql, merge, insert

I have multiple tables that all have the same columns, but in different order. I want to merge them all together. I've created an empty table with the standard columns in the order I would like. I've tried inserting with

```
insert into master_table select * from table1;
```

but that doesn't work because of the differing column order - some of the values end up in the wrong columns. What is the best way to create one table out of them all in the order specified in my empty master table?

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with many columns and many tables, you can use the information_schema to get the columns.  You can loop through all the tables you want to insert from and run this in a plpgsql procedure, replacing table1 with a variable:

```
EXECUTE (
SELECT
'insert into master_table
    (' || string_agg(quote_ident(column_name), ',') || ')
 SELECT ' || string_agg('p.' || quote_ident(column_name), ',') || '
 FROM   table1 p '
 FROM   information_schema.columns raw
 WHERE  table_name  = 'master_table');
```

Comment: Looks good, but there seems to be a closing parenthesis `)` missing somewhere. [still counting ...]

Comment: you are right -- the one at the very end to complete execute(), edited answer

Comment: also added quotes around 'master_table' since it's a string value in the information_schema table

Comment: BTW: you can avoid a lots of quoting and `||` worries by using the `format()` function.

Answer (score 0):

just indicate the proper order in the select

instead of

```
  select *
```

if you want 3 field on second posiition.

```
  select field1, field3, field2
```

or you can use the INSERT sintaxis

```
 INSERT INTO master_table (field1, field3, field2)
     SELECT *
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I tried this earlier but it didn't seem to work, probably some error on my part, let me try again